# Sqlplus is not starting up

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Sqlplus on Windows 10 is silently exiting back to command prompt after 1-2 seconds with no messages, no matter what params supplied, -H for example. This happened on previous 18c version too after working for a long time without problem. After removing 18c and installing 19c, it worked the first day only, and then the same behavior.

Comment: Which Oracle version / edition on which MS Windows version is it?

Comment: Current Oracle version is 19.3 Enterprise on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I was kind of *hoping* that it was Windows **Home**; Oracle was never certified on it. Yes, it works quite well in most cases, but - who knows, maybe you hit the problem. Apparently, that's not the case. Then I thought that maybe it is about a logon trigger which does log off, but - if you installed a brand new database, who'd write such a trigger? Strange ... and I don't have any more ideas at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Try launching command prompt as administrator.

Comment: I do run cmd as admin every time

Comment: Do you have any antivirus s/w? Have you checked quarantine files, a/v logs?

Comment: Also have you tried sqlcl?

Comment: Also check/show your login.sql

Comment: There is no antivirus, I don't have sqlcl and I am not sure what trying that would give me. There is no login.sql either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it using MS Visual Studio: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-debug-and-profile-any-exe-with-visual-studio/